# login page code for python using flask and psql code not working

Tags: python, authentication, flask-sqlalchemy, psql

i am trying this code for logging in account which has database in psql, but for some reason i am only able to render the error page, and no success page

```
username= request.form.get("uname")
password = request.form.get("psw")


usernamedata= db.execute("SELECT username FROM register WHERE username=:username",{"username":username}).fetchone()
passworddata= db.execute("SELECT password FROM register WHERE username=:username",{"username":username}).fetchone()
if usernamedata is None:
    return render_template("error.html")
else:
    for pass_word in passworddata:
        if True:
            return redirect(url_for('lsuccess'))

        else:
            return render_template("error.html")
```

the uname and psw are the username and password taken from the form.

Comment: are you receiving any error message?
Why are you looping through `passworddata` btw?

Comment: no i am not receiving any error message, this code is being executed, its just that only the error.html file is being rendered and not the lsuccess.html.   and i am looping over password data to check if the password is right for the specific user

Comment: Note you are not `rendering` a page, you are `redirecting` to a url..  In your views.py make sure the function that handles this url is actually rendering a page.

Comment: i am sorry i am not catching up with what you are try to say :/

Comment: Haha.. Sorry, my bad, I had django in mind.. Check the route of lsuccess and make sure to `render` a template

Comment: <form action="/lsuccess">
 this is in my login.html page

Comment: You have to have a function called lsuccess, and the function needs to render a template

Comment: @app.route('loginpage')
def lsuccess():
   return render_template('whatever.html')

Now you can use the `url_for('lsuccess')`

This will call the route function which will render the desired template

Comment: Do you have a `lsuccess` route function?

Comment: the above code is from the lsuccess only, which is rendering only the error page                                                                @app.route("/lsuccess",methods=['GET','POST'])
def lsuccess(): *the code i mentioned*                                                                my login page have the form which when submitted should be rendering the lsuccess page, and if the username and password are wrong it should give the error page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form submits request to `lsuccess` which just renders a success page without querying user details.

Copy the query to another route (POST request only is preferably) in total you will have 3 routes.

1. Login route that renders the login  page.
2. Check route that the form sends data to, to validate the user and either returns the error page or the success page.
3. The success page that gets rendered if the user is validated.

Final code should look like:

```
@app.route("/login", methods=['GET','POST'])
def login():
    return render_template("login.html") 

@app.route('/validate', methods=['POST'])
def validate():
    uname= request.form.get("uname")
    psw = request.form.get("psw")
    usernamedata= db.execute("SELECT username FROM register WHERE username=:username",{"username":username}).fetchone()
    passworddata= db.execute("SELECT password FROM register WHERE username=:username",{"username":username}).fetchone()
    if usernamedata is None:
        return render_template("error.html")
    else:
        return redirect(url_for('lsuccess'))

@app.route("/lsuccess", methods=['GET','POST'])
def lsuccess():
    return render_template("lsuccess.html")
```

Finally, change your form's `action` attribute to `action=/validate`

Comment: i copied the same code, but now error page is coming even when password adn username is correct. i just had to change the route('/validate', methods=['get','post']. because it was giving me an error as method not allowed.

Comment: About the form giving you an error concerning `method not allowed`, change your form's `method` attribute to POST..... And this code will ONLY render ERROR page IF usernamedata is None.....

After querying usernamedata, try printing it out in to the command line and see the result...

Comment: thank you so much, i did how you told an now its working properly. thank you again. now just the thing is when my username is correct an password is wrong its still rendering success. can you tell me the code to do so...

Comment: in the if statement where you checked `usernamedata is None`, check if  `psw` is equal to `passworddata` that will solve the issue, cause right now, you are only checking for the username.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.. Happy coding :D

Answer (score 0):

```
from flask import Flask, url_for, render_template, redirect
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    ...
    ...
            #Don't know why you added an if Statement here
            if True:
                # 'lsuccess' is the name of your route function you are redirecting to
                return redirect(url_for('lsuccess'))

            #this statement is never reachable
            else:
                return render_template("error.html")

#You NEED A ROUTE FUNCTION named lsuccess, in this function, `render a template`
@app.route('/success')
def lsuccess():
    return render_template('your_success.html')
```

`if True` won't have any effect on your code, since  the condition will always be True and the `else` block will never run.

The `if usernamedata is None` condition is enough condition to make sure the user exists.

In the else statement, passworddata returns just one value e.g `"password"`, using a for loop will iterate through each character e.g `p`, `a` and so on.

Remove the for loop, remove the `if True` and then remove the  `else` block.

Final code should look like:

```
from flask import Flask, url_for, render_template, redirect
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    username = request.form.get("uname")
    password = request.form.get("psw")

    usernamedata = db.execute("SELECT username FROM register WHERE username=:username",
                              {"username": username}).fetchone()
    passworddata = db.execute("SELECT password FROM register WHERE username=:username",
                              {"username": username}).fetchone()
    if usernamedata is None:
        return render_template("error.html")
    else:
        return redirect(url_for('lsuccess'))

@app.route('/success')
def lsuccess():
    return render_template('your_success.html')
```

Comment: when i made it like this only the success page is being rendered now, even the password and username is incorrect. and i added that if statment to use the else:

Comment: i  got the same result after editing, i have posted my code below, i don't understand why this is not working now.

Answer (score 0):

```
@app.route("/login", methods=['GET','POST'])
def login():
    return render_template("login.html")
    uname= request.form.get("uname")
    psw = request.form.get("psw")

    usernamedata= db.execute("SELECT username FROM register WHERE username=:username",{"username":username}).fetchone()
    passworddata= db.execute("SELECT password FROM register WHERE username=:username",{"username":username}).fetchone()
    if usernamedata is None:
        return render_template("error.html")
    else:
        return redirect(url_for('lsuccess'))
    @app.route("/lsuccess",methods=['GET','POST'])
    def lsuccess():
        return render_template("lsuccess.html")
```

this is what my code looks like now exactly how you told, but still its rendering the success page only. this time

Comment: Yes.. It's rendering success cause the username was found.

Comment: its rendering success even when the username and password are not present in database. error page is not being rendered

Comment: Try printing usernamedata and check what it returns.

Comment: {% extends "layout.html" %}


{% block body %}
    <h1>sucessfully loggedin</h1>

    <a href="{{ url_for('page') }}"> go ahead</a>

    {{usernamedata}}
{% endblock %}                                        this is my lsuccess code, but it isnt printing anything,           return redirect(url_for('lsuccess',usernamedata=usernamedata)) in my application.py added like this

Comment: You have to pass a variable to your view if you want to use the variable.. `url_for('lsucces', variable=usernamedata`

Comment: can you pls give the code with variable added in this and where to add in the lsuccess.html file. in my computer i am not getting the error page, which i am supposed to get when the username and data is not in database. i am stuck in this code

Comment: I just took a look at your code again, you are returning a template before checking any logic.

Comment: Where does your form submit its data to?

Comment: Form is submitted to action=/lsuccess

Comment: You are submitting user info to lsuccess, but the logic of check user is in `login` which is why your code isn't working.. Copy the code from uname to another route.. I'll Post an answer right now on how the code should look like.